# How Terminable Middleware works in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I found terminable middleware in laravel which is very useful to get work done after response has been sent to browser. Awesome setup done by Laravel!!

I'm wondering how this is working? I mean after response has been sent to the browser is PHP still running?

Please explain me if anyone know that.

Thanks, Jimit

Comment: Haven't read the code, but Laravel probably captures the output buffer, then does something with the Terminable Middleware, then does some magic with the buffer contents to create a `Response` object, thus creating the actual response. I'm just guessing though, I don't have the code handy so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5:

As stated in the `Symfony\Component\HttpKerne\TerminableInterface::terminate()` method, 
this method will be called after sending the response and before shutting down the kernel.

So clearly, you will get the response object in this method but if you change something in response object
that will not reflect to the response object that is sent to browser.

A good use case of this method is, during integration testing, if some task needed to be performed just before shutting down the application.